# ctypes.Structure with bit fields are not setting values correctly

Tags: python, structure, ctypes, bit-fields

I have the following in C

```c
#include <stdio.h>

struct Demo {
    char f1:8;
    int f2:21;
    char f3:2;
    char f4:1;
};

int main()
{
    struct Demo d = {1, 15, 3, 1};
    printf("%ld\n", sizeof(d));
    printf("f1=%d|f2=%d|f3=%d|f4=%d", d.f1, d.f2, d.f3, d.f4);

    return 0;
}
```

which prints

```
4
f1=1|f2=15|f3=-1|f4=-1
```

I have been using bit-fields with `ctypes.Structure`, and have implemented the above structure.

My issue is that no matter what I do, I am unable to set the values for my fields.

I have the following in Python 3.8.10, and 3.9.9:

```py
from ctypes import Structure, c_byte, c_int, sizeof
class Demo(Structure):
  _fields_ = [
    ('f1', c_byte, 8),
    ('f2', c_int, 21),
    ('f3', c_byte, 2),
    ('f4', c_byte, 1)
  ]

print(sizeof(Demo))

d = Demo.from_buffer_copy(b'\x01\x0f\x00\xe0')
print(f'{d.f1=}|{d.f2=}|{d.f3=}|{d.f4=}')
```

Prints

```
1
4
d.f1=1|d.f2=15|d.f3=0|d.f4=0
```

Hence the C and Python definitions are equivalent, but they set values are not.

The bytes object (`b'\x01\x0f\x00\xe0'`) is the binary representation of the C struct with the following values (as shown above):

- `f1`: 1
- `f2`: 15
- `f3`: -1 (3, overflow makes it -1)
- `f4`: -1 (1, overflow makes it -1)

Manual setting, or `from_buffer_copy`, achieve nothing; `f3`, and `f4` remain 0.

Could someone help me understand how to set `f3`, and `f4`, and also access their values in a bit form of their corresponding field size.

#### Notes

With scouring https://bugs.python.org, and past [GitHub Issues](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues), I finally came across [#59324](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/59324) (11y Old), and [#97588](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/97588), which cover the same issues as mine, with no recourse.

Though there seems to be a pending [PR](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/97702) which may resolve this issue in upcoming Python releases.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Initialize the structure using a constructor and dump the resulting bytes. The bits aren’t getting assigned where you think.

Comment: I put this up on GitHub as well, and got some guidance. This is an issue with how the interpreter handles structs, because as such the program is well defined, but the interpreter seems to grab incorrect bits/bytes for setting and getting when size or offset is too large as is in this case. Refer https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/102844.

Comment: Did you try the `Demo2` solution?  It lays the bits out correctly on my compiler.  Yes, it doesn't match the types in the C structure you are using, but it should work.

Comment: The Demo2 solution did work as I have mentioned, and thank you for that idea. I'll try if I could get the C code to be changed. Nonetheless, thanks for your guidance, and I hope the implementation is fixed sooner than later.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not using the same type across the entire 32-bit field.  When the type changes, a new packing is started and aligned on a type-sized boundary.  See comments below and the size of the original and correct structure in bytes.  Note that `bytes()` can be used on a `Structure` instance to see the resulting bytes after construction.

```py
import ctypes as ct

class Demo1(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = (('f1', ct.c_byte, 8),  # 1 byte started
                ('f2', ct.c_int, 21),  # 1 int started (3 bytes padding, then 4 bytes)
                ('f3', ct.c_byte, 2),  # 1 byte started
                ('f4', ct.c_byte, 1))  # included in previous byte
                # 3 bytes structure padding so 'f2' will be aligned in an array of Demo1
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Demo1(f1={self.f1}, f2={self.f2}, f3={self.f3}, f4={self.f4})'

class Demo2(ct.Structure):
    _fields_ = (('f1', ct.c_int32, 8),  # one int started
                ('f2', ct.c_int32, 21), # included in previous int
                ('f3', ct.c_int32, 2),  # included in previous int
                ('f4', ct.c_int32, 1))  # included in previous int
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Demo2(f1={self.f1}, f2={self.f2}, f3={self.f3}, f4={self.f4})'

print(f'{ct.sizeof(Demo1)=}')
print(f'{ct.sizeof(Demo2)=}')

d1 = Demo1(1, 15, -1, -1)  # Set the fields in the constructor
print(d1, bytes(d1))       # Resulting structure and bytes.

d2 = Demo2.from_buffer_copy(b'\x01\x0f\x00\xe0')
print(d2, bytes(d2))
d2 = Demo2(1, 15, -1, -1)
print(d2, bytes(d2))
```

Output:

```
ct.sizeof(Demo1)=12
ct.sizeof(Demo2)=4
Demo1(f1=1, f2=15, f3=-1, f4=-1) b'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x00'
Demo2(f1=1, f2=15, f3=-1, f4=-1) b'\x01\x0f\x00\xe0'
Demo2(f1=1, f2=15, f3=-1, f4=-1) b'\x01\x0f\x00\xe0'
```

Comment: I would like to correct one aspect of your code. The structure I have defined prints the size as 4, and its confirmed by `ct.alignment` printing 1 (i.e. alignment requirement of 1). So I don't think there is any padding or realignment taking place, and even if it were according to your example, the values should get updated, which they are not. Using the same datatype can not be done due to the C interface of the struct being implemented as such, and this is a small part of the entire struct. Is there any way to make this work with the current definition of the struct?

Comment: The structure you have defined is equivalent to my `Demo1`. It’s size is 12. If you are somehow getting 4, then edit your question to prove it. My example shows exactly what works.  Changing the type starts the definition of a new set of bits. If you want 32 bits packed into 4 bytes, this is the way to do it.  If C is doing it that way it should give a size of 12 as well.

Comment: I have edited my question to provide details which prove the equivalence to a C struct, and that the size of both is 4, and not 12. Since the padding and other such features are compiler dependent, it is not necessary that the struct should come up to size 4. The exact underlying logic is too complex for me to find out just at a glance, but as per C standard there is no uniform implementation, which states that change of type indicates change of byte. It is ABI, and platform dependent. I ran your above given code, and got the size as 4, hence commented on it.

Comment: And your compiler/OS details then, since it’s implementation dependent. The Demo2 implementation still gives you the correct layout.

Comment: Also, I get `ct.alignment(Demo1)` as 4, not 1.  assigning `_pack_ = 1` gives a size of 6.  My compiler is MSVS 15.0 and OS Windows 10 64-bit, and Python 3.11.2 64-bit.

Comment: Compiler GCC 8.2. Platform RHEL8 x86-64. Python 3.8.10 and 3.9.9. Demo2 does give the correct layout but if fields are added before or after it skews the struct and sizes, and I can not alter the C implementation hence my restriction. Though a [fix](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/97702) for this is under work, and should be out soon, Python 3.11 onwards. The only difference between the C and Python implementation as I just saw is what you mentioned, the difference between the alignments of the structs. In my case `_pack_ = 1` is also giving a size of 4 on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out; using a consistent type for bitfields is a valid workaround given you are not restricted by anything.

But seeing as this is an interpreter issue, there is an upcoming [PR](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/97702) which should fix this soon,and will also be backported to v3.11.

So for anyone who lands here looking for a solution:

- Use the same type across the bit-field value definitions,
- Upgrade to v3.11 or later, or
- Backport the solution on your own if you have enough experience with C, by referring the [PR](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/97702), and editing the source code, to create a custom build.